# How to change the order in which variables are printed in prolog?

Tags: prolog, prolog-toplevel

This is a homework problem, but I just need a simple question answered.  I am supposed to print all the possible ways a knight can jump on a chess board from it's position.  I am getting the correct numbers but I don't seem to get the correct output that I want.  For example:

```
 ?- knight(8,1,R,C)
```

is supposed to print out the output as:

```
C = 3
R = 7;
C = 2
R = 6;
```

But I get the exact opposite as in:

```
R = 7,
C = 3;
R = 6,
C = 2.
```

here is my code:

```
knight(C, R, C2, R2):-
      C2 is C - 1,R2 is R + 2,
      withinBoard(C2,R2)
   ;  C2 is C + 1,R2 is R + 2,
      withinBoard(C2,R2)
   ;  C2 is C + 2, R2 is R + 1,
      withinBoard(C2,R2)
   ;  C2 is C + 2, R2 is R - 1,
      withinBoard(C2,R2)
   ;  C2 is C + 1, R2 is R - 2,
      withinBoard(C2,R2)
   ;  C2 is C - 1, R2 is R - 2,
      withinBoard(C2,R2)
   ;  C2 is C - 2, R2 is R - 1,
      withinBoard(C2,R2)
   ;  C2 is C - 2, R2 is R + 1,
      withinBoard(C2,R2).

 withinBoard(Col,Row):-
        Row < 9, Row > 0, Col < 9, Col > 0.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
?- C=C,knight(8,1,R,C).
   C = 3, R = 7
;  C = 2, R = 6.
```

Both orders are fine and mean exactly the same.

Many current Prolog systems print variables in the very order determined by `read_term(Query, [variable_names(VN_list)]).` which they use to read a term. So the variable that occurs leftmost is the first to print its answer substitution.

In the past, some systems ordered `VN_list` by the name of the variables. Which actually did make sense as the order was left unspecified by the standard. In the meantime, this has been corrected in [Cor.3](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/iso-prolog/WDCor3#C5). It seems your homework dates from an earlier time since `'C' @< 'R'`. To get the very precise order, you now need to add an artificial goal in front. I took `C=C` which is always true.

All that said, I do not believe that your instructor will insist on the very precise order.